# Deriving the gradient of a multivariable function taking matrices as input?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've been tasked with deriving the gradient for the following non-convex function and I'd like to verify whether my solution / progress is correct so far (I'm not too confident with calculus):

$$F(U, V) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2 + \frac{\lambda}{2}(||U||^2_F + ||V||^2_F)$$

Where $M, U, V$ are matrices, $u_i$ and $v_j$ refer to the $i$th row and $j$th row of $U$ and $V$ respectively, and $\lambda$ is a variable denoting some learning rate.

I've obtained the following so far for the partial derivative with respect to $U$:

$$\dfrac{\partial F(U,V)}{\partial U} =-\sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2 + \lambda(||U||^2_F)$$

But I'm a bit unsure about taking the derivative for $\frac{\lambda}{2}(||U||^2_F + ||V||^2_F)$. I think what I have above is correct as $V$ would be treated like a constant (since we're doing the partial derivation with respect to $U$). I assume the approach for taking the partial derivative with respect to $V$ would be the same.

Comment: What exactly is $\Omega$ in this context? If you're simply adding over all indices $i,j$, then the first sum can be rewritten as $\|M - UV\|_F^2$.

Comment: No, I do not believe that your result so far is correct.

Comment: In terms of [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities), what you're looking for is the denominator-layout derivative. With that in mind, we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial U}\|U\|_F^2 = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial U}\operatorname{tr}(U^TU) = 2U
$$
(using the row of the table corresponding to $\frac{\partial}{\partial X}\operatorname{tr}(X^TAX)$)

Comment: Hi Ben (thank you!), $\Omega$ in this context represents a set of entries taken from some training set of data. As for the rewritten first sum, wouldn't it be more like $||M - UV^T||^2_F$ (I'm probably wrong on this)

Comment: That's right, typo on my part.

Comment: by any chance, does the training set correspond to a *submatrix* of $M$? In other words, do the known $M_{ij}$ necessarily form a grid within the matrix $M$?

Comment: Hm. I'm actually unsure about that. After checking the definition of a submatrix, I would likely say no. As $\Omega$ is determined by taking a random portion of the data.

Comment: But what exactly do you mean by "random"? If "random" means randomly selecting rows and columns from which to measure each entry, then we have a submatrix. Otherwise, we don't

Comment: Got it -- then I think we do, since it is randomly selected. Sorry about that!

Comment: It looks to me like you missed the point of my comment. There are different ways of selecting things randomly. The particular fashion in which things are "randomly selected" makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tricky part here is computing
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial U}\sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2.
$$
One approach is to go entry by entry. Note that the $p,q$ entry of this partial derivative is equal to the partial derivative of the sum with respect to the $p,q$ entry of $U$. We note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial U_{pq}} \sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2 &= 
\sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}} \frac{\partial}{\partial U_{pq}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2
\\ & = 
\sum_{j \in S_p} \frac{\partial}{\partial U_{pq}}(M_{pj}-u_pv_{j}^T)^2
\\ & = 
\sum_{j \in S_p} 2(M_{pj}-u_pv_{j}^T)\frac{\partial}{\partial U_{pq}}(M_{pj}-u_pv_{j}^T)
\\ & = \sum_{j \in S_p} 2(M_{pj}-u_pv_{j}^T)(-V_{jq})
= -2\sum_{j \in S_p} (M_{pj}-u_pv_{j}^T)V_{jq}.
\end{align}
$$
Here, $S_p = \{j: (p,j) \in \Omega\}$.

---

If the known entries form a submatrix, then let $J_1$ denote the matrix whose rows are the rows of the identity matrix corresponding to the selected rows of $M$, and let $J_2$ denote the matrix whose columns are the columns are the columns of the identity matrix corresponding to the selected columns. We can then write the sum as
$$
\sum_{(i,j)\in{\Omega}}(M_{ij}-u_iv_{j}^T)^2 = \|J_1(M - UV^T)J_2\|_F^2.
$$
We compute
$$
\begin{align}
\|J_1(M - &[U+H]V^T)J_2\|_F^2 =
\operatorname{tr}([J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2][J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2]^T)
\\ & = 
\|J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2\|_F^2 
-2 \operatorname{tr}([J_1HV^TJ_2][J_1MJ_2]^T) + o(\|H\|)
\\ & = 
\|J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2\|_F^2 
-2 \operatorname{tr}([V^TJ_2][J_1MJ_2]^TJ_1H) + o(\|H\|)
\\ & = 
\|J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2\|_F^2 + 
 \operatorname{tr}([-2J_1^TJ_1MJ_2J_2^TV]^TH) + o(\|H\|).
\end{align}
$$
Correspondingly, we compute
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial U}\|J_1(M - [U+H]V^T)J_2\|_F^2
= -2 J_1^TJ_1MJ_2J_2^TV.
$$
To make some sense of this: we can write this product in the form $-2 J_1^T[J_1MJ_2][J_2^TV]$. $[J_1MJ_2]$ is the known submatrix of $M$, and $V$ is the submatrix of $V$ obtained by taking only the rows of $V$ corresponding to known columns of $M$.

Answer (score 0):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Capture the index constraint using the Hadamard product $(\odot)$ and a projection matrix
$$\eqalign{
P_{ik} &= \begin{cases}
1\quad{\rm if\,}(i,k)\in\Omega \\
0\quad{\rm otherwise}
\end{cases} \\
P &= P\odot P
 \qquad\; ({\rm projective\,property}) \\
\sum_{(i,k)\in\Omega}\!\!M_{ik} &= P\odot M
 \qquad ({\rm same\,size\,as\,}M) \\
}$$
Denote the standard vector basis as {$e_k$} and the standard matrix basis as $\big\{E_{ik} \doteq e_ie_k^T\big\}\;$
and the trace/Frobenius product using a colon, i.e.
$$A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{k=1}^nA_{ik}B_{ik} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
For typing convenience, define the indexed matrix
$$A_{ik} \;=\; P\odot\Big(Ue_i(Ve_k)^T-M\Big) \;=\; P\odot\Big(UE_{ik}V^T-M\Big)$$
Assembling all of this with the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) allows us to write the objective function and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 F &= \tfrac 12A_{ik}:A_{ik} + \tfrac \lambda 2\big(U:U + V:V\big) \\
dF &= A_{ik}:dA_{ik} + \lambda\big(U:dU + V:dV\big) \\
 &= A_{ik}:\big(dU\,E_{ik}V^T+UE_{ik}\,dV^T\big) +\lambda\big(U:dU+V:dV\big) \\
 &= (VE_{ik}^TA_{ik}+\lambda U):dU + (A_{ik}^TUE_{ik}+\lambda V):dV \\
}$$
Holding $V$ constant (i.e. setting $\,dV=0$) yields the gradient with respect to $U$, while holding $U$ constant yields the gradient with respect to $V$
$$\eqalign{
\p{F}{U} &= VE_{ik}^TA_{ik}+\lambda U, \qquad
\p{F}{V} &= A_{ik}^TUE_{ik}+\lambda V \\
}$$

---

A quick note about the Frobenius and Hadamard products. They are mutually commutative, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A\odot B &= B\odot A \\
C:A\odot B &= C\odot A:B \\
}$$
In addition, the properties of the trace allow the terms in a Frobenius product to be rearranged in a number of equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
CA:B &= A:C^TB = C:BA^T \\
}$$
The thing to keep in mind in these manipulations is that the matrix on each side of a Frobenius (or Hadamard) product must have exactly the same dimensions.